# How to make RelativeLayout Scrollable?

Tags: android

I want to make scrollable layout becuase my TextView has long text. I searched and found some solution, like create a ScrollView inside my RelativeLayout and create another RelativeLayout inside there. and changed my xml code like this. but nothing happened.

this is my xml code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.arsh.fina.IntroActivity">

    <include layout="@layout/content"/>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="55dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/surv1"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />


        <TextView
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="A VERY 
VERY 
VERy 
VERY TEXT"/>


    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/a1"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="55dp">


    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/a2"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/header"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Where do I go wrong?

Answer (score 2):

In order for a vertical Layout to be scrollable, its layout_height must be "wrap_content". If you set it to "match_parent" the layout will always be as high as the parent and there will be nothing to scroll to because android will thing it is already fully visible.

Change to

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="55dp">
```

The same goes for a horizontal layout of course, but then it's layout_width that must be "wrap_content". You have no orientation set on your layout so it will be horizontal by default.